# Что такое "тютелька"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Есть выражение "тютелька в тютельку". А что, собственно, такое "тютелька"? Или это просто звукоподражание (но тогда — чему?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0) дает вполне подробный ответ.

Во-первых, данное слово встречается практически только лишь в одном выражении "тютелька в тютельку".
Во-вторых, в качестве исходного слова дается "тютя", обозначающее "удар, попадание". Получается, что "тютя в тютю" означает точное попадание в одно и то же место (например, топором при столярной работе). Почему же получилась именно "тютелька"? А тут можно предположить, что произошло смешение со словом "утелька", обозначавшее крошку или малютку.

Comment: Wikitionary — это неавторитетный источник, который может редактировать любой пользователь. я давно в вики-проектах, но не знаю среди его редакторов ни одного с учёными званиями/степенями в области лингвистики. Полагаю, что ссылаться на него в ответах — плохая практика. // Правда, в данном случае статья [**ссылается**](http://bit.ly/2qnJOKc) на доктора филологических наук Мокиенко. // «Можно предположить» — также неавторитетный источник, у Мокиенко «тютелька — уменьшительное от тютя». Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Тютелька это повреждение, след оставленный топором в дереве после удара, который обозначается словом тюкать.
В плотницком деле множество разных ударов топором. Один из них, примерно средней силы, с небольшим замахом издает звук, который ни с чем не перепутаешь, а именно ТЮК. Отсюда и описание удара - тюкать. След оставленный топором в дереве называется тютя. Попадание серией ударов в одно и то же место это признак мастерства плотника. Эта техника называется тютя в тютю. Так могут большинство плотников, а вот точно попадать из раза в раз в небольшую тютю могут уже не все. Отсюда и выражение тютелька в тютельку, как описание точь в точь, в самый раз. Есть еще одно выражение - попасть в тютельку. Означает сделать что-то трудновыполнимое в точности, как требуется.

Comment: Слов нет, версия есть, но вот аргументы будут ли?

Answer (score 0):

Тютя — это не след от топора, а сдвоенный удар: **тю** (удар поперек волокон), **тя** (удар под углом).
Тю — тюкнуть, нанести удар сверху.
Тя — тяпнуть, отделить, оттяпать, тяпка.
Тютелька в тютельку означает точно работать топором, поражать в одном месте.

Comment: Это логическое заключение (и другие тоже) надо бы чем-то обосновать. Желательно цитировать источник.

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется, что происхождение тюти не от работы топором, а от разметочных работ, от слова тут. Например, отпили от сюда от сюда, от тута до тута, от тюти до тюти. Он был мастер своего дела и он отпилил тютя в тютю, тютелька в тютельку.